# Failed to push a custom struct allocated with "new" in queue

Tags: c++, c++11, struct, dynamic-memory-allocation

I have an issue about pushing structs allocated with `new` operator.

Here follows my queue declaration, my struct and the code where I allocate a new struct and try to push it in my queue:

```
std::queue<data_pkt> my_queue;

typedef struct data_pkt {
    int sockfd;
    std::string payload;
    int payload_size;
} data_packet;

data_packet *data = new data_packet;
if (!data) {
    printf("Failed to allocate data_packet to enqueue pkt\n");
    exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
}

/* filling struct's fields... */

my_queue.push(data);
```

When compiling with flags `-Wall -std=c++11`, it gives:

```
error: no matching function for call to ‘std::queue<data_pkt>::push(data_packet*&)’
     queue_to_internet_1.push(data);

no known conversion for argument 1 from ‘data_packet* 
{aka data_pkt*}’ to ‘const value_type& {aka const data_pkt&}’
```

So I tried changing my queue declaration including `&`, so that it could accept pointers to struct, but it says:

```
error: template argument 1 is invalid
   std::queue<&data_pkt> q;
                       ^
QOSManager.h:57:23: error: template argument 2 is invalid
```

I saw that `new` returns a `void *`, so my queue should be capable of storing pointers to `data_packet` structs, but I don't know what I'm doing wrong.

Comment: _`data_packet *data = new data_packet;`_ Why are you using `new` at all, and not simply `data_packet data;`?

Comment: Because doing `data_packet data = new data_packet;` the compiler says `error: conversion from ‘data_packet* {aka data_pkt*}’ to non-scalar type ‘data_packet {aka data_pkt}’ requested
  data_packet data = new data_packet;`. I read that people passing from C to C++, like me, should get used to use `new` instead of `malloc`.

Comment: As mentioned you don't need and don't want dynamic memory allocation in this case, what needs to be done regarding this is managed in the `std::queue` already.

Comment: @elmazzun: Actually, You should get used to use neither new nor malloc

Comment: It's just as πάντα ῥεῖ said, by allocating a simple struct I can push it in my queue.
Thank you, post your comment as answer and I'll accept it.

Comment: And read about RAII: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Resource_Acquisition_Is_Initialization

Comment: I read that "calling std::queue::pop() calls the removed element's destructor".
Is there no way to store the result of a popped element from a queue?
`pop()` return `void`, I don't understand.

Answer (score 0):

In your code compiler produce syntax error about push of value of wrong type,
that can be fixed by:

```
my_queue.push(*data);
```

side note in C++ you not need `typedef struct data_pkt{} data_packet;`
you can write `struct data_packet {};` and then write `data_packet data;`,
without `struct` keyword, because of C++ not C.

But your memory allocation is waste of CPU cycles,
so you can write:

```
data_pkt data;
my_queue.push(data);
```

Or to remove useless copy:

```
my_queue.push(data_pkt());
data_pkt &data = my_queue.back();
//fill data here
```

Comment: Why leave a memory leak? There is no need for `new` here. The compiler doesn't want `new`.

Comment: @juanchopanza Question about why code not compiling, not about program optimization, any way (1) I remove memory leak, (2) in my last code variant there are no memory leak

Comment: `data_packet data;` also compiles.

Comment: @juanchopanza my comment that in C you have to always write `struct data_pkt` or use `typedef` to not write `struct` keyword, in C++ you can write `data_pkt` and no need `typedef`

Comment: And my comment is that the compiler error can be fixed by removing the dynamic allocation completely. There is no reason to use it here. Why would the compiler "want" a `unique_ptr`?

Comment: @juanchopanza and my original answer contains section about useless memory allocation and how to not use it, what is your point?

Comment: @juanchopanza ok, I can change `compiler want` to `compiler produce syntax error about push of value of wrong type` this looks better?

Answer (score 0):

Two options to fix compilation error:

1. Do not use dynamic allocation as already mentioned.
2. Store pointers in the queue instead of structs and this is correct declaration for this `std::queue<data_pkt*> my_queue;`

Well, templates and std:: library is a big topic, but to quickly understand where the compiler error comes from - consider the my_queue as plain array. You either declare array of structures and set structure in each element or you declare array of pointers and set pointers.

Comment: In your opinion, what is the most performant way? 
Queue of structs or queue of pointers to structs?

Comment: This is no difference in performance of the queue itself. There is additional indirection when accessing fields in the data_pkt structure in case pointers are stored, but I believe there is no performance penalty on modern processors. Also, having queue of pointers will require a little more memory (extra pointer per each element in the queue).

Comment: Thanks for the clarification